# Ionic - how to prevent error "TS2339: Property XXX does not exist on type"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm doing a simple loop through an Array and calling a method on each element.

```
this.scene.manager.scenes.forEach((scene) => {
  if(scene.refresh){
    scene.refresh();
  }
});
```

This code works, but it shows a compile error:

> error TS2339: Property 'refresh' does not exist on type 'Scene'.

It's because one of array items is different from the others.

How can I prevent this compile error, since the condition `if(scene.refresh){` is already handling it?

Comment: We'll need to see the type definitions to give you a good answer, but perhaps you're looking for `if ('refresh' in scene)`? That will check whether the property exists without accessing it.

Comment: `if (scene?.refresh) {...}`

Comment: @NicholasTower wow that's a good answer as well. It prevent's this error from happen. You can post it as answer.

Comment: @anderlaini Just a suggestion - Ideally you should handle it the other way, i.e. identify why one of the items does not have `refresh()` method. And if its an candidate for one, add, even if its an empty method. This way your interface will remain consistent!

Comment: using `if(scene['refresh'])` and `scene['refresh']();` seems a poor solution but works with no compiling errors

Comment: As you see in my code,`(scene as any)` is used to assert that the `scene` variable should be treated as the `any` type, which allows accessing any property without `TypeScript` checking for type compatibility,with this way, the compiler won't raise an error when accessing the `refresh` property!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using a type assertion could be a better approach to inform TypeScript that the property does exist!

Something like this:

```
this.scene.manager.scenes.forEach((scene) => {
  if ('refresh' in scene) {
    (scene as any).refresh();
  }
});
```

Comment: this worked as well, but I ended up using using `if(scene['refresh'])` and `scene['refresh']();`